# Enemy object in a game does not show up

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a simple shoot em up. I want to create an enemy object that for the moment has an x and y start position and a speed and an update function that just decreases on the y-axis. I haven't written an object class before but I think I'm doing it wrong.

Here's my code so far:

```
//enemy object
var SpawnEnemy = function(x, y, speed) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.speed = speed;
   this.update = function() {
      this.x -= this.speed;
      ctx.drawImage(drawing,235,753,100,54,this.x,this.y,80,48);
   };
}
```

I then call the enemy:

```
if (distance >= 5) {
   var enemy3 = new SpawnEnemy(800, 400, 2);
   enemy3.update();
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you're doing something wrong? It looks correct to me!

Comment: Methods should be defined by `this.prototype.methodName = function () {}` instead of `this.methodName = function () {}`. This way you create function object once, not once per parent object.

Comment: im getting nothing on the screen. but are you saying my code is correct. if that's the case then im in trouble! :)